# Resize widget inside QTreeWidget (set with setItemWidget)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a `QListWidget` inside a `QTreeWidget` and I want it to automatically adjust its height as rows are added or removed. I got the `QListWidget` autosizing working but it breaks when it's inside the `QTreeWidget`, the `QListWidget` grows in size but the `QTreeWidget` doesn't adjust to it properly and other rows get covered.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, sip
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MyListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def sizeHint(self):
        width = super().sizeHint().width()
        height = sum([self.sizeHintForRow(i) for i in range(self.count())]) + 5
        return QtCore.QSize(width, height)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()

item1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['item1'])
item2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['item2'])
item3 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['item3'])

list_widget = MyListWidget()
list_widget.addItems(list('abcd'))

tree.setItemWidget(item1, 0, list_widget)

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add row")
button.clicked.connect(lambda: [list_widget.addItem("New row"),
                                list_widget.adjustSize(),
                                tree.adjustSize(),
                                tree.updateGeometry()
                                ])

container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
container.setLayout(layout)

layout.addWidget(tree)
layout.addWidget(button)

container.show()
list_widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Initial Output:

[image]

Output After clicking Add New:

[image]

As you can see in the second image, `item2` is now covered by the expanded list widget, the desired output would be to shift the `item2`, such that after adding new item inside the list widget doesn't cover the item below it in the same tree widget.

Comment: Could you show an image of what you get and what you want to get since your post is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the tree and connect the model's `rowsInserted` and `rowsRemoved` signals, then update geometries accordingly, including that of the item:

```
class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def setItemWidget(self, item, column, widget):
        super().setItemWidget(item, column, widget)
        if isinstance(widget, MyListWidget):
            widget.model().rowsInserted.connect(
                lambda: self.updateItemWidget(item, column))
            widget.model().rowsRemoved.connect(
                lambda: self.updateItemWidget(item, column))

    def updateItemWidget(self, item, column):
        widget = self.itemWidget(item, column)
        item.setSizeHint(column, widget.sizeHint())
        self.updateGeometries()
```